# Spring Boot Admin with Eureka and Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, spring-boot-admin

**EDIT/SOLUTION**:

I've got it, partly thanks to @anemyte's comment. Although the `eureka.hostname` Property was not the issue at play (though it did warrant correction), looking more closely got me to the true cause of the problem: the network interface in use, port forwarding and (bad) luck.

The services that I chose for this prototypical implementation were those that have port-forwardings in a production setting (I must have unfortunately forgotten to add a port-forwarding to the example service below - dumb, though I do not know if this would have helped).

When a Docker Swarm service has a port forwarding, the container has an additional bridge interface in addition to the overlay interface which is used for internal container-to-container communication.

Unfortunately, the client services were choosing to register with Eureka with their *bridge interface IP* as the advertised IP instead of the internal swarm IP - possibly because that is what `InetAddress.getLocalhost()` (which is internally used by Spring Cloud) would return in that case.

This led me to erroneously believe that Spring Boot Admin *could* reach these services - as I externally could, when it in fact could not as the wrong IP was being advertised. Using `cURL` to verify this only compounded the confusion as I was using the *overlay IP* to check whether the services can communicate, which is not the one that was being registered with Eureka.

The (provisional) solution to the issue was setting the [`spring.cloud.inetutils.preferred-networks`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/html/appendix.html) setting to `10.0`, which is the default IP address pool (more specifically: `10.0.0.0/8`) for the internal swarm networks (documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-mode/#configuring-default-address-pools)). There is also a blacklist approach using `spring.cloud.inetutils.ignored-networks`, however I prefer not to use it.

In this case, client applications advertised their actual swarm overlay IP to Eureka, and SBA was able to reach them.

I do find it a bit odd that I did not get any error messages from SBA, and will be opening an issue on their tracker. Perhaps I was simply doing something wrong.

(original question follows)

---

I have the following setup:

1. Service discovery using Eureka (with `eureka.client.fetch-registry=true` and `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true`)
2. Spring Boot Admin running in the same application as Eureka, with `spring.boot.admin.context-path=/admin`
3. Keycloak integration, such that:

   - SBA itself uses a service account to poll the various `/actuator` endpoints of my client applications.
   - The SBA UI itself is protected via a login page which expects an administrative login.

Locally, this setup works. When I start my `eureka-server` application together with client applications, I see the following correct behaviour:

1. Eureka running on e.g. `localhost:8761`
2. Client applications successfully registering with Eureka via IP registration (`eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true`)
3. SBA running at e.g. `localhost:8761/admin` and discovering my services
4. `localhost:8761/admin` correctly redirects to my Keycloak login page, and login correctly provides a session for the SBA UI
5. SBA itself successfully polling the `/actuator` endpoints of any registered applications.

However, I have issues replicating this setup inside a Docker Swarm.

I have two Docker Services, let's say `eureka-server` and `client-api` - both are created using the same network and the containers can reach each other via this network (via e.g. `curl`). `eureka-server` correctly starts and `client-api` registers with Eureka right away.

Attempting to navigate to `eureka_url/admin` correctly shows the Keycloak login page and redirects back to the Spring Boot Admin UI after a successful login. However, no applications are registered and I cannot figure out why.

I've attempted to enable more debug/trace logging, but I see absolutely no logs; it's as if SBA is simply not fetching the Eureka registry.

Does anyone know of a way to troubleshoot this behaviour? Has anyone had this issue?

EDIT:

I'm not quite sure which settings may be pertinent to the issue, but here are some of my configuration files (as code snippets since they're not that small, I hope that's OK):

`application.yaml`

(Includes base eureka properties, SBA properties, and Keycloak properties for SBA)

```js
---
eureka:
  hostname: localhost
  port: 8761
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    # Registry must be fetched so that Spring Boot Admin knows that there are registered applications
    fetch-registry: true 
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.hostname}:${eureka.port}/eureka/
  instance:
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 10
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 30
  environment: eureka-test-${user.name}
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: false # Intentionally disabled for non-production

spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        prefer-ip: true
      # Since we are running in Eureka, "/" is already the root path for Eureka itself
      # Register SBA under the "/admin" path
      context-path: /admin
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true


keycloak:
  realm: ${realm}
  auth-server-url: ${auth_url}
  # Client ID
  resource: spring-boot-admin-automated
  # Client secret used for service account grant
  credentials:
    secret: ${client_secret}
  ssl-required: external
  autodetect-bearer-only: true
  use-resource-role-mappings: false
  token-minimum-time-to-live: 90
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
```

`build.gradle`

```js
// Versioning / Spring parents poms
apply from: new File(project(':buildscripts').projectDir, '/dm-versions.gradle')

configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}

ext {
    springBootAdminVersion = '2.3.1'
    keycloakVersion = '11.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server'
    implementation "de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-server:${springBootAdminVersion}"
    implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile "org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:${keycloakVersion}"

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:${keycloakVersion}"
    }
}
```

---

The actual application code:

```js
package com.app.eureka;

import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.EnableAdminServer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableAdminServer
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EurekaServer.class, args);
}

}
```

Keycloak configuration:

```js
package com.app.eureka.keycloak.config;

import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.web.client.HttpHeadersProvider;
import org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal;
import org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext;
import org.keycloak.OAuth2Constants;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Objects;

@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KeycloakSpringBootProperties.class)
class KeycloakConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String X_API_KEY = System.getProperty("sba_api_key");

@Value("${keycloak.token-minimum-time-to-live:60}")
private int tokenMinimumTimeToLive;

/**
 * {@link HttpHeadersProvider} used to populate the {@link HttpHeaders} for
 * accessing the state of the disovered clients.
 *
 * @param keycloak
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public HttpHeadersProvider keycloakBearerAuthHeaderProvider(final Keycloak keycloak) {
    return provider -> {
        String accessToken = keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessTokenString();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("X-Api-Key", X_API_KEY);
        headers.add("X-Authorization-Token", "keycloak-bearer " + accessToken);
        return headers;
    };
}

/**
 * The Keycloak Admin client that provides the service-account Access-Token
 *
 * @param props
 * @return keycloakClient the prepared admin client
 */
@Bean
public Keycloak keycloak(KeycloakSpringBootProperties props) {
    final String secretString = "secret";
    Keycloak keycloakAdminClient = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(props.getAuthServerUrl())
            .realm(props.getRealm())
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .clientId(props.getResource())
            .clientSecret((String) props.getCredentials().get(secretString))
            .build();

    keycloakAdminClient.tokenManager().setMinTokenValidity(tokenMinimumTimeToLive);
    return keycloakAdminClient;
}

/**
 * Put the SBA UI behind a Keycloak-secured login page.
 * 
 * @param http
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**/*.css", "/admin/img/**", "/admin/third-party/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
    grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");
    grantedAuthorityMapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);

    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(buildSessionRegistry());
}

@Bean
protected SessionRegistry buildSessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}

/**
 * Allows to inject requests scoped wrapper for {@link KeycloakSecurityContext}.
 * <p>
 * Returns the {@link KeycloakSecurityContext} from the Spring
 * {@link ServletRequestAttributes}'s {@link Principal}.
 * <p>
 * The principal must support retrieval of the KeycloakSecurityContext, so at
 * this point, only {@link KeycloakPrincipal} values and
 * {@link KeycloakAuthenticationToken} are supported.
 *
 * @return the current <code>KeycloakSecurityContext</code>
 */
@Bean
@Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public KeycloakSecurityContext provideKeycloakSecurityContext() {

    ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    Principal principal = Objects.requireNonNull(attributes).getRequest().getUserPrincipal();
    if (principal == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (principal instanceof KeycloakAuthenticationToken) {
        principal = (Principal) ((KeycloakAuthenticationToken) principal).getPrincipal();
    }

    if (principal instanceof KeycloakPrincipal<?>) {
        return ((KeycloakPrincipal<?>) principal).getKeycloakSecurityContext();
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

KeycloakConfigurationResolver

(separate class to prevent circular bean dependency that happens for some reason)

```js
package com.app.eureka.keycloak.config;

import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfigurationResolver {

/**
 * Load Keycloak configuration from application.properties or application.yml
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
}

}
```

Logout controller

```js
package com.app.eureka.keycloak.config;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
class LogoutController {

/**
 * Logs the current user out, preventing access to the SBA UI
 * @param request
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
@PostMapping("/admin/logout")
public String logout(final HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    request.logout();
    return "redirect:/admin";
}
}
```

---

I unfortunately do not have a `docker-compose.yaml` as our deployment is done mostly through Ansible, and anonymizing those scripts is rather difficult.

The services are ultimately created as follows (using `docker service create`):
(some of these networks may not be relevant as this is a local swarm running on my personal node, of note are the `swarm` networks)

```sh
dev@ws:~$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
3ba4a65c319f        bridge              bridge              local
21065811cbff        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
ti1ksbdxlouo        services            overlay             swarm
c59778b105b5        host                host                local
379lzdi0ljp4        ingress             overlay             swarm
dd92d2f75a31        none                null                local
```

`eureka-server` `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM registry/image:latest
MAINTAINER "dev@com.app"
COPY eureka-server.jar /home/myuser/eureka-server.jar
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
CMD /usr/bin/java -jar \
    -Xmx523351K -Xss1M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M \
    -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=115625K \
    -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom eureka-server.jar \
    --server.port=8761; sh
```

Eureka/SBA app Docker swarm service:

```sh
dev@ws:~$ docker service create --name eureka-server -p 8080:8761 --replicas 1 --network services --hostname eureka-server --limit-cpu 1 --limit-memory 768m eureka-server
```

Client applications are then started as follows:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM registry/image:latest
MAINTAINER "dev@com.app"
COPY client-api.jar /home/myuser/client-api.jar
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
CMD /usr/bin/java -jar \
    -Xmx523351K -Xss1M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M \
    -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=115625K \
    -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Deureka.instance.hostname=client-api client-api.jar \
    --eureka.zone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka --server.port=0; sh
```

And then created as Swarm services as follows:

```sh
dev@ws:~$ docker service create --name client-api --replicas 1 --network services --hostname client-api --limit-cpu 1 --limit-memory 768m client-api
```

On the client side, of note are the following `eureka.client` settings:

```js
eureka:
  name: ${spring.application.name}
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    instanceId: ${spring.cloud.client.hostname}:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instanceId:${random.int}}
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
```

---

That's all I can think of right now. The created docker services are running in the same network and can ping each other by IP as well as by hostname (cannot show output right now as I am not actively working on this at the moment, unfortunately).

In the Eureka UI I can, in fact, see my client applications registered and running - it's only SBA which does not seem to notice that there are any.

Comment: Can you provide some materials to reproduce the issue? Maybe a docker-compose file?

Comment: @anemyte Thank you for your comment. I've added everything that I could think of - please let me know if you require any additional info.

Comment: As an aside: I've opted not to include any additional Keycloak configuration as that part of the application seems to work without any issues, and so as to prevent this question from becoming more bloated than it already is.

Comment: Thanks for such details but unfortunately I see no problem here except for `eureka.hostname` in `application.yaml`. Shouldn't it be `eureka-server` instead? Also looking at some examples (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html#spring-cloud-eureka-server-standalone-mode) it's usually `eureka.instance.hostname`.

Comment: Hm, good catch. I don't see how that could cause the issue, but sometimes with docker it can be the oddest things. I'll give an update as soon as I can try it out. Thanks!

Comment: @anemyte I was able to get this to work, partly through taking a closer look at pretty much every single configuration property and container setting - prompted by your comment. I've edited the question with the solution, but I do want to credit your comment which got me looking in that direction. If you would like to re-word your comment as an answer with the suggestion of looking more closely at the network configuration, I would be glad to give you the bounty. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. I did as you said about the comment but I'd rather prefer it not to be an accepted answer. If anyone else stumble into this they will be reading answers first and your solution there is far better than my weak lead.

Answer (score 2):

I found nothing wrong with the configuration you have presented. The only weak lead I see is `eureka.hostname=localhost` from `application.yml`. `localhost` and loopback IPs are two things that better to be avoided with swarm. I think you should check if it isn't something network related.